# Text flickers on hover CSS

Tags: html, css, hover

When hovering over the image to prompt the text to appear, the text and banner flutter once you put the mouse over it. How can this be prevented.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Here's the sample. http://jsfiddle.net/a3mcmbby/

Html:

```
<div id="container-content">
   <div id="design-background">
   </div>
   <div id="content">
      <div id="table-content">
         <table align="center">
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td colspan="2" valign="bottom" style="font-family:ralewayregular; color: rgb(37,37,37); font-size: 110%; line-height: 150%;">
                  </td>
                  <td><a href="/events/default/view/"><img src="/images/layout/layoutImg6.png" alt="" width="310" height="182"></a>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <a href="/events/default/view/"><img src="/images/layout/layoutImg4.jpg" alt="" width="304" height="194"></a>
                     <h3>EXAMPLE</h3>
                  </td>
                  <td rowspan="2">
                     <a href="/events/default/view/"><img src="/images/layout/layoutImg5.jpg" alt="" width="311" height="406"></a>
                     <h3>EXAMPLE</h3>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <a href="/events/default/view/"><img src="/images/layout/layoutImg1.jpg" alt="" width="308" height="195"></a>
                     <h3>EXAMPLE</h3>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <a href="/events/default/view/"><img src="/images/layout/layoutImg3.jpg" alt="" width="304" height="195"></a>
                     <h3>EXAMPLE</h3>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <a href="/events/default/view/"><img src="/images/layout/layoutImg2.jpg" alt="" width="308" height="195"></a>
                     <h3>EXAMPLE</h3>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td colspan="3" style="text-align:center; font-family: Semibold; color: rgb(165,97,11); font-size:300%;">Serving St. Catharines and Niagara Region</td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container-content{
    position:relative;
     margin: 0 auto;
     width:100%;
     min-height:700px;         
     background-color:#FFF;
}

#design-background{
    position:absolute;
    height:350px;    
    top:50%;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;    
    margin-top: -145px;    
    background: url('../images/background-dec.jpg');    
}

#content{     
    position:relative;    
    margin: 0 auto;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    width:980px;

}

#table-content{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-30px;
}

#table-content table tr td{
    position: relative;
    padding:8px;
}

#table-content table tr td h3{
    display:none;
}

#table-content table tr td a:hover + h3{
    color:#FFF;
    display:block;
    position: absolute;       
    z-index:10;    
    margin: auto;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:8px;
    right:10px;              
    font-family: ralewayregular;
    height:50px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    text-align: center;
    padding-top:25px;
    font-size: 200%;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a3mcmbby/

Comment: You might be working with some pre-existing markup but I'm going to be **that guy** and say that you shouldn't use tables for layout and depreciated attributes like *align*.

Comment: Your key problem aside, I would suggest staying consistent by pulling out your in-line styles from your HTML markup and placing them in CSS rules if you can. Keeping a separation of concerns will help you in the long run. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML, nest `h3` within `a`, then adjust your CSS accordingly.

As it is now, `h3` is being placed over top of the `a` tag when the `a` tag is hovered over. This prevents hovering from working so the hover status is removed. Then, it picks up the cursor hovering again because it is no longer covered - continuing in an endless loop.

Comment: Great solution. And makes more structural sense. Here's a [demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/a3mcmbby/3/).

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
#table-content table tr td:hover h3{ #do something ... }
```

Comment: This is the answer.  The reason is because you are triggering your `:hover` on the `a`, but immediately covering it with a div, causing the `a` to lose it's `:hover`-ed state.  Repeat xInfinity

Comment: However, the `<h3>` still covers the `<a>` and [prevents clicking the link](http://jsfiddle.net/a3mcmbby/2/) if the mouse is over the `<h3>`, which might not be desirable.

Answer (score 0):

When you display the h3, it is intercepting the hover in the underlying element, so it is no longer hovered. Then h3 is not displayed, the underlying element is hovered again , and so on

set

```
#table-content table tr td h3 {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

to avoid it

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a3mcmbby/1/)

Comment: `pointer-events` is fantastic, but it's too bad [only IE 11+](http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events) supports it :(